# Web scraping mouseover labels of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, web-scraping

I have a website where some interesting information appears if I hover my mouse over a particular part of an image.

I'd like to extract this into a structured format, i.e.:

```
Zürich, 2000 und mehr
Hinwil, 1400 bis 1600
Zug, 2000 und mehr
...
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

To see the live example, just scroll to the first image here:
https://www.republik.ch/2020/01/27/stadt-land-graben-die-hotspots

If I hover over a different part of the image, I see a different label appearing.

I couldn't find this information easily in the source code. There are at least hundreds of parts to the image, so manually going through it would take quite some time.

What would be the best way to scrape the data that I see when hovering over different parts?

Comment: Your code trials please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
document.querySelector('figure[data-css-18r0zrg] svg').addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
if(document.querySelector('div[data-css-5rrfwp]') !== null)
{
    console.log(document.querySelector('div[data-css-5rrfwp]').innerText.replace(/\n/g, " "));
}

});
```

**Updated**

```
document.querySelector('figure[data-css-18r0zrg] svg').addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  if(document.querySelector('div[data-css-5rrfwp]') !== null)
  {
    console.log(document.querySelector('div[data-css-5rrfwp]').innerText.replace(/\n/g, " "));
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll("[data-css-11e8ajt]").forEach(el=>{
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', { 'bubbles': true }));
    },5000);
});
```

Paste above code and hit Enter key in the console of [webpage](https://www.republik.ch/2020/01/27/stadt-land-graben-die-hotspots)

Comment: Yes, this is very close to what I'm looking for! The only hurdle is now that I need to hover over each piece of the image to get the values printed. Ideally, there would be a for-loop that just goes over each part of the image so I don't have to do this manually.

Comment: You can collect geoJSON data from the [link](https://cdn.republik.space/s3/republik-assets/assets/geo/bfs-g2g19.json?1). Also I have updated my answer as per your requirement. Mouseover event is automatically firing with the help of ForEach loop and collecting data on console. Please mark it as Answered if it has been resolved your query.